# Applications of the DGIM algorithm

Tags: counting, streaming-algorithm

In the field of mining of data streams the algorithm of Datar-Gionis-Indyk-Motwani (**DGIM**, M. Datar, A. Gionis, P. Indyk, and R. Motwani, “Maintaining stream statistics over sliding windows,” SIAM J. Computing 31, pp. 1794–1813, 2002.) is known. Given is a [binary stream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitstream) with a [sliding window](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_algorithm#Sliding_window_model) of length $N$, where $N$ is larger than the computer memory. It is used to answer the question of how many are there 1s in the sub-window consisting last k bits, where $1\le k\le N$.

I understand the algorithm, but I cannot come up even with a single example, where DGIM would beat the naive counting.

Let me explain. It is claimed that the advantage of the algorithm is reduced storage. The whole window can be represented with just $\mathcal{O}(\log^2N)$ storage, from where the counting question for any $1\le k\le N$ can be answered. Assume that at any instance of time we would like to know how many 1s are in the ranges $[k_i,N]$, where $i=1,N_q$. The number of queries should not be too large, i.e., $N_q\ll N$ for, otherwise, $N_q>memory$, and we cannot digest the results of the algorithm. But then, it is sufficient to have just $N_q$ simple counters, which are updated every time step!

The only scenario which would merit the DGIM algorithm is when $k_i$ are not known in advance, and the calculations need to be adjusted on the fly. But why would it be the case? I suppose that DGIM should be used for plotting time-dependent histograms, but the bin size of the histograms is usually fixed, isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the streaming model, old inputs are gone and cannot be read again unless explicitly copied to the memory. Therefore, you cannot use a simple counter: how to determine whether the counter should be decremented when an input element goes out of the window?

In fact, if the window size is $n$ then exact window counting requires $n$ bits of memory. The point of streaming algorithms is to overcome this barrier by clever approximation algorithms.

Comment: Thank you. That is what is written in every book. I was thinking differently: we have $N_q$ counters, which are *incremented* with a certain delay. But they are *never decremented*. Let the "counter-0" ($c_0$) be the most recent one and the "counter-1" $c_1$ will be a counter delayed by, let us say, 1729. Notice, we can talk about the delays because per definition of the stream, it also carries time-stamps. Then, if we want to know how many 1s are in the interval $[N-1729, N]$ we just take $c_0-c_1$. What is wrong with this appoach?

Comment: You cannot maintain $c_1$ without remembering last 1729 elements. $c_1$ should be incremented now (after N'th element read) if and only N-1792+1'th element is 1. You don't have access to the "delayed stream" in general.

Comment: A streaming algorithm for window statistics is beneficial if the *window size* is already too large to fit in the memory. If the window size is small, you can do things exactly even if the data stream is infinite.

Comment: "You don't have access to the "delayed stream" in general"--good point. After thinking a bit I understood your reasoning. Thank you.